# Handling questions marks on prefixed sphinx indexes

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I am running an RT index with the following settings:

```
min_word_len = 1
min_infix_len = 3
dict = keywords
```

This is working fine. However, when I search for "do you realize??" (which is a value in
the index) it does not find it. Both "do you realize" and "do you realize*" find multiple
hits.

I tried the following all without luck.

`ignore_chars = U+003F`

Escaping the string `"do you realize\?\?"`

`$cl->EscapeString( "do you realize??" );`

I'm still searching for other items to try, but wanted to check here to see if anyone had ideas.

Answer (score 0):

So if I drop the min_prefix_len and min_word_len directives a keep just dict=keywords, this works without the need to escape the question mark (?).

Wildcard searching also still works, though it seems to act a bit different.

I've seen conflicting information on this. Can anyone confirm that dict=keywords by itself is sufficient for wildcard searching? Why would you also use
min_prefix_len/min_infix_len?